# trying to use Sql stored procedure in MFC application

Tags: c#, .net, mfc

I am new to .net and written the code to validate userid and password using sql stored procedure and code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace *********
{
    public static class DBHelper
    {

        public static bool ValidateUser(string userID, string password)
        {
            bool isCustomerExists = false;

            string constr = "Data Source = ****-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = *******; Integrated Security = True";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Validate_User"))
                {

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();

                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader["UserID"] != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            isCustomerExists = true;
                        }

                    }
                    con.Close();
                }

            }

            return isCustomerExists;
        }



        internal static bool AddNewCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            bool isCustomerCreated = false;

            try
            {
                string constr = "Data Source = *****-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = *****; Integrated Security = True";

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InserNewCustomer"))
                    {

                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PFirstName", customer.FirstName);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PLastName", customer.LastName);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PLoginID", customer.LoginID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCustomerPassword", customer.CustomerPassword);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PConfirmCustomerPassword", customer.ConfirmCustomerPassword);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PBirthday", customer.Birthday);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCustomerAddress", customer.CustomerAddress);
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();

                        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                            if (reader.RecordsAffected == 1)
                            {
                                isCustomerCreated = true;
                            }
                        con.Close();
                    }

                }


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isCustomerCreated = false;
            }

            return isCustomerCreated;
        }
    }
}
```

I want use the above code in MFC application project. Can anyone help me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrap the functionality inside a mixed-mode assembly (using C++/CLI), and expose a native interface.

Answer (score 1):

It is a late reply but it may be useful for people learning mfc DB Connection.

Recently i got chance to Learn MFC and SQL Server Stored Procedure, i checked for many solutions and found this one i am sharing with you, Hope it will help.

I am Using VS2012 and SQL Server 2008.

I used your code data and tried to replicate your scenario.
Create Stored Procedures Accordingly in SQL.

```
bool ClassName::ValidateUser(string userID, string password)
{
    bool isCustomerExists = false;

    CDatabase database;

    CString strConn;

    strConn = L"Data Source = ****-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = *******; Integrated Security = True";
    // your connection string, i was using ODBC Data source.


    TRY
    {

        database.Open(NULL,0,0,strConn);
        CRecordset recordset(&database);
        CString strQuery;

        strQuery.Format(L"{CALL Validate_User('%s','%s')}",userID,password);


        recordset.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly,strQuery,CRecordset::readOnly);

        if(!recordset.IsBOF())
        {
            isCustomerExists = true;
        }

        recordset.Close();

        database.Close();
    }
    CATCH(CDBException,e)
    {
        MessageBox(L"Exception: "+e->m_strError);
    }
    END_CATCH;
    return isCustomerExists;
}

bool ClassName::AddNewCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    bool isCustomerCreated;
    CDatabase database;

    CString strConn;

    strConn = L"Data Source = ****-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = *******; Integrated Security = True";
    //your connection string, i was using ODBC Data source.


    TRY
    {

        database.Open(NULL,0,0,strConn);
        CRecordset recordset(&database);
        CString strQuery;

        strQuery.Format(L"{CALL InserNewCustomer('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')}",customer.FirstName,customer.LastName,customer.LoginID,customer.CustomerPassword,customer.ConfirmCustomerPassword,customer.Birthday,customer.CustomerAddress);

        database.ExecuteSQL(strQuery);

        isCustomerCreated = true; 
        database.Close();
    }
    CATCH(CDBException,e)
    {
        MessageBox(L"Exception: "+e->m_strError);
        isCustomerCreated = false;
    }
    END_CATCH;
    return isCustomerCreated;
}
```

If you have any doubts, you can ask me, i will try to solve it.

Comment: I'm adding this comment in 2020, when this really helped Me, using Visual C++ 2017 and on WIndows Sever 2016 , running SQL Server. This is the only working example and blog on the first few pages of google search that yielded a precise result on using CALL to execute a parameterised SQL Server procedure from a MFC app, using a CDatabase class. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

It is real easy to port this code to MFC. Take a look at `CDatabase` and `CRecordset` classes. You can also find the following article helpful: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/storedprocedures/article.php/c1167/Calling-Stored-Procedures.htm

Comment: [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"**Provide context for links:** Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*

Answer (score -1):

`_T("{CALL your_sp_name(param list)}"` is the only syntax that works for the `CRecordset` if the sp returns a result set, pay close attention to braces `{}` and `()`